# What is the difference between the two OO methodologies in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've been using the below, I've seen other code using function() { } and then using the this keyword, what is the difference here, have I actually instantiated an object below?

```
    var MyObj = {
 propertyOne: 'a',
            Method: (function() {
                function MyFuncOne() {}
                function MyFuncTwo() {}
                return {
                    MyFuncOne: MyFuncOne,
                    MyFuncTwo: MyFuncTwo
                }
            })()
        }
```

Comment: I must be a shut in, because I have never seen an object construction like that.

Comment: Of course, you're returning an object from the function. Seems a little weird as-is, though.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney: It ain't just you.  That code looks downright odd to me.  I'm going to bet it doesn't do what it ought to.

Comment: That snippet is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: The braces are serving the place of terminating semicolons. It runs fine in IE9 and Chrome, but you're right in that it's not valid ECMAScript.

Comment: Don't be distracted by the outer braces `{ }`, they create a block that has no useful effect (but isn't harmful either).

Comment: THanks for help everyone, going to try get rid of outer curlies and see if that works. (it's all working at the moment but if its not syntactially correct  i dont want to use it. Ill go with tjdett's solution. I don't understand exactly what {} is used for, I've used it alot thought it was for storing properties in an clasS?

Comment: Guys IM sorry!! Forgot to put in the Method outer property, is that valid now?

Comment: I'm not using this for Desktop, its for a jquerymobile site, and its running fine without errors all desktop browsers I've tried + Android + iPhone, iPhone opera hasn't worked but that's the only browser that hasn't liked it and I've tried a whole lot of Android browsers

Answer (score 2):

The only reason I can think of for doing something like this is if you wanted to have some private variables that were shared between the two functions (after changing it to make it legal javascript):

```
var MyObj = (function() {
        var x,y,z;    // these will be accessible only to 
                      // the MyFuncOne and MyFuncTwo functions
        function MyFuncOneA() {}
        function MyFuncTwoA() {}
        return {
            MyFuncOne: MyFuncOneA,
            MyFuncTwo: MyFuncTwoA
        }
    })();
```

I had to change your syntax to even make it work because as you had it myObj = {{...}} which isn't very useful and may have not even been valid.

Other than this private, but shared variables notion, it's just extra (and confusing) syntax for declaring two methods on an object which there are much clearer ways to do.

If you weren't using the private variables, then the above example is functionally the same as this much simpler syntax which makes a lot more sense to me:

```
var MyObj = {
    MyFuncOne: function() {},
    MyFuncTwo: function() {}        
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you've instantiated a "singleton" object with two methods.

I believe the outer curly braces are unnecessary, and you could just write:

```
var MyObj = 
    (function() {
        function MyFuncOne() {}
        function MyFuncTwo() {}
        return {
            MyFuncOne: MyFuncOne,
            MyFuncTwo: MyFuncTwo
        };
    })();
```

Another way to do it is:

```
var MyObj = 
    (function() {
        var obj = {};
        obj.MyFuncOne = function() {};
        obj.MyFuncTwo = function() {};
        return obj;
    })();
```

Wrapping your JS in `(function() { /* code here */ })()` is good practice for preventing  variables leaking into global scope. In this case, you're using it to assemble an object.

Answer (score 1):

Using a function with the `this` keyword allows you to do some more things than are possible (or, at least, easy) with an object literal (which is what your anonymous function above returns).  Most commonly, creating "types".

```
function Animal () { }
Animal.prototype.speak = function () {
    return "";
};
var dog = new Animal();
dog instanceof Animal;    // returns true
```

This also makes inheritance easier:

```
function Feline () { }
Feline.prototype = new Animal;
Feline.prototype.speak = function () {
    return "meow";
};
function Lion () { }
Lion.prototype = new Feline;
Lion.prototype.speak = function () {
    return "roar";
};
function Cat () { }
Cat.prototype = new Feline;
var leo = new Lion();
var baxter = new Cat();
leo.speak();       // returns "roar"
baxter.speak();    // returns "meow" - from prototype chain
leo instanceof Feline;   // returns true 
leo instanceof Animal;   // returns true
leo instanceof Cat;      // returns false
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/hEnJf/